# jQuery - Detect element removal inside contenteditable div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, contenteditable

I have an input element in my contenteditable `<div>`, sample code:

```
<div class="ucclass" contenteditable="true">
   <input id="abc" class="js_xxx">
</div>
```

I have a piece of code which used to paste an input with auto generated id into the `<div>`.

How can I grab the input id when I delete it?

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Is input elements id static??

Comment: Are you asking how to detect removal, or how to get the ID? Both should be trivial if you're the one removing the element ?

Comment: I need to get the Id only when the element is removed, and the Id is auto generated so I don't know it. I will add some explanation.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a [`MutationObserver`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM%2FDOM_Mutation_Observers) to achieve this. To track any sort of node removed from your `contenteditable` element, observe the following example

```
var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
    mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {

        //console.log($(mutation.removedNodes)); // <<-- includes text nodes as well

        $(mutation.removedNodes).each(function(value, index) {
            if(this.nodeType === 1) {
                console.log(this.id) // abc
            }
        });
    });
});

var config = { attributes: true, childList: true, characterData: true };

observer.observe($('.ucclass')[0], config);
```

### [JSFiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/rzvdLcyq/)

Answer (score 0):

MutationObserver is perfect if you don't need pre-IE11 support.

Otherwise, you could listen for a `keydown` event on `.ucclass`, collect all of its descendants with ids, and set a timer that checks if any element has been deleted:

```
$('.ucclass').on('keydown', function(e) {
  var ids= $(this).find('[id]'),
      self= $(this);
  setTimeout(function() {
    ids.each(function() {
      if(!self.find('#'+this.id).length) {
        //do something
      }
    });
  });
});
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/wmnq7L6f/)